# How do I call a specific CSS class name in an xsl: when test= statement, so the test proves true?

Tags: css, xslt

I have a rotator component that acts one way on the homepage, another way on every other page. I want to strip out one more attribute when it is on the homepage within the CSS div class "tabimage."

```
<div class="tabimage">
<xsl:apply-templates select="RotatorComponent[@Name = 'ProfileRotator']"/>
```

Here is the complete code. The first test is what I am working on, the when and otherwise works fine. Since posting this question, I have come to the conclusion that I need to not just select the CSS, but somehow differentiate if it is a parent or not of the rotator component, right?

```
<xsl:template match="RotatorComponent[@Name='ProfileRotator']/Navigation/Page" mode="Rotator">
        <xsl:param name="visible" />

        <xsl:if test="parent::node/@RotatorComponent = 'tabimage'">     
                <div class="assessimg"><a href="{@URL}" style="margin-left:500px"><img src="images/{@Thumbnail}" alt="{@ProfileName}" width="189" height="213"/></a></div>      
        </xsl:if>                   

        <xsl:choose>        
            <xsl:when test="not(/HomePage)">
                <xsl:if test="@Thumbnail">
                    <a href="{@URL}">
                        <img src="images/{@Thumbnail}" alt="{@Title}"/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:if>
                <p class="quote"><xsl:value-of select="@Quote"/></p>    
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                    <div class="module">
                        <div class="assessbox">
                            <div class="studentprofileboxinner">
                                <xsl:variable name="profileVar" select="/*/Page[@Name = 'Profile']"/>   
                                <div class="assessimg"><a href="{@URL}" style="margin-left:-5px"><img src="images/{@Thumbnail}" alt="{@ProfileName}" width="189" height="113"/></a></div            
                                <div class="assesscopy">
                                    <h3><xsl:value-of select="@ProfileType"/> Story</h3>
                                    <p><xsl:value-of select="@Abstract"/></p>
                                    <a href="{@URL}" class="assessimage"></a> <!--assessimage-->
                                    <!--assessimage-->
                                </div>          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- module -->   
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is no question being asked. Also, in order for this to be understood and somebody to be able to help, you need to provide the exact source XML file and the complete XSLT code. You may also explain what the transformation is required to do.

Comment: I changed the above post, does that help?

Comment: Is this syntax correct for this logic:
test if the parent of the rotator component's name is tabimage.

    <xsl:if test="parent::node/@RotatorComponent = 'tabimage'">

Comment: user1272772: No. Nothing is correct when no XML document is shown.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?998dejscu2febam

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, it depends on what node is the current one - so it depends on what statements are called before the choose element.
If the current node is the div one, then the test should work; if it isn't, then it won't work.

Comment: so you are saying my syntax for test="(@class='tabimage')" is correct?

Second, you are asking what order the test is?

Comment: Your syntax is correct, but test="@class='tabimage'" is valid also. You do not need the brackets. But please include your source so we can verify. Make sure  the case is correct, and you don't need test="@Class='tabimage'"

Comment: Alright, I included my default.xsl which is where the html is - look at line 998 and my include-rotator.xsl - look at line 81

http://www.mediafire.com/?998dejscu2febam

Comment: @user1272772 can't figure out this one; I agree with Dimitre that the source XML/html is needed in order to be able to say something sensible about this.